# How to add an image to gallery in android studio emulator

Tags: android-studio

I have tried dragging and dropping an image into the emulator and it places it in the documents folder, and does not show in the gallery. I have tried the Device File Explorer and am able to copy images but none of them show up in the gallery. I have tried remounting the sd card with no success.

When I take a photo with the camera in the emulator it shows up in the gallery and I can see it here. If I drag & drop another .jpg file here and synchronize, this test.jpg file doesn't show up in the gallery.

[image: Device File Explorer]

Comment: After Drag & Dropping. Is your image showing in 'Android SDK built for x86/Downloads' or Any other directory?

Comment: When I drag & drop, I can go to Files and I see it under Downloads but haven't been able to get it into the gallery.

Comment: It is required to scan images with MediaStorage API in case to show it in Recent. But, you are putting images directly instead of scanning them using MediaStorage. In this case, Just `Cold Boot` your emulator after adding images. It'll show all images in `Recent`.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately when I try to cold boot I get "Device Manager, Illegal char *> at index 0: *.lock"..... I saw a solution that says to delete "hardware-qemu.ini.lock" but when I try to do that it says the fold is in use... do you happen to know of a way to get an image into the gallery without having to cold boot?

Comment: Had to restart my laptop and was able to cold boot and the image showed in the gallery. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, sometimes need to restart the system to interrupt the process of the emulator. Glad to hear that the problem is solved!!!